# how to multiply two fields in a form in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

everyone. I am making accounting program in oracle APEX. I need to multiply two fields in a form and to save the result in a third field. I searched for that in youtube and here in stackoverflow but did not find anything aprropriate. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Dynamic action** is a simple option; create it on both items (so that it fires when any item's contents has changed). What will it do? **Set value** of the resulting item.

- Action: set value
- set type: PL/SQL expression
- expression: `:P1_VAL1 * :P1_VAL2`
- items to submit: `P1_VAL1, P1_VAL2`
- affected element: item, `P1_RESULT`

That's all.

Comment: I clicked on "edit page" and looked for "Dynamic action" in the interface but did not find it.

Comment: Right-click the item; you'll find it there.